# Making DependsOn work in RoboBinding

Tags: java, android, mvvm, data-binding, robobinding

In RoboBinding there is the annotation `DependsOnStateOf`.
When using it in a PresentationModel like this:

```
@PresentationModel
class GreetingPresentationModel {
    String firstname;
    String lastname;
    //getters and setters for both
    @DependsOnStateOf("firstname")
    public boolean isLastnameInputEnabled() {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(firstname);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. The following binding will be always false and doesn't change.

```
bind:enabled="{lastnameInputEnabled}"
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the RoboBinding AndroidMVVM example, it is crucial to implement `HasPresentationModelChangeSupport` using `PresentationModelChangeSupport` and make setters call `firePropertyChange`:

```
@PresentationModel
public class GreetingPresentationModel implements HasPresentationModelChangeSupport {
    PresentationModelChangeSupport changeSupport;

    @Override
    public PresentationModelChangeSupport getPresentationModelChangeSupport() {
        return changeSupport;
    }

    public GreetingPresentationModel() {
        changeSupport = new PresentationModelChangeSupport(this);
    }
    // Rest of the code here
    // Then change each setter, e.g.
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange("firstname");
    }
}
```

Comment: you can add RoboBinding aspectJ support to avoid manually writing firePropertyChange code. It will auto weave in firePropertyChange code for you.

Comment: @Cheng is there a way we can do this or firePropertyChange() from within an ItemPresentationModel ?

Comment: @Cheng btw much thanks for the work you're doing for RoboBinding :)

Comment: @beerBear You can do all that PresentationModel can do in ItemPresentationModel. ItemPresentationModel is a conceptual extension of PresentationModel.